# MVC 4 Submit button not responding unable to call controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My view submit button is not responding.It's Unable to call [Httppost] method please check my code below.When ever i click on submit there is no response from view or controller. My httpGet and Httppost method have same name.

```
* View



    @model MT566_PSS.Models.EventController

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Assign Controller";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }


    @using (Html.BeginForm("EventAssign", "ShowMessage", new { extMsgId = Model.ExternalMessageId, userId = Session["commitId"], currentController = Model.COMMIT_ID }, FormMethod.Post, new { id  = "formPosted1" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="BNYMInputBox" id="BlotterSelection">
        <div class="InputBoxHeader">
            <h3>Assign Controller</h3>
        </div>
        <div><span id="postResult"></span></div>
        <div id="inputFields">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ID, Model.UserList, "Select", new { @id = "SelectedValue" })


            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "GetExtMsg")
        </div>
    </div>
}




* Controller

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EventAssign(int extMsgId = 0, string userId = "", string currentController = "")
        {
   T_REVIEW_EVENT_ID revent = _dbContext.T_REVIEW_EVENT_ID.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EXT_MSG_ID == extMsgId);
            if (revent != null)
            {
                revent.CTRL_COMMIT_ID = userId;
            }
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var log = new T_LOG
            {
                EXT_MSG_ID = extMsgId,
                COMMIT_ID = userId,
                AFFECTED_DATE = DateTime.Now,
                COMMENTS = currentController + " Changed to:" + userId,
                CHANGED_COLUMN = "Table: " + "T_Review_Event_Id, " + "Column: " + "CTRL_INDICATOR",
                OLD_VALUE = currentController,
                NEW_VALUE = "Controller: " + userId,
                APPLIED_LEVEL = ""
            };
            _dbContext.T_LOG.Add(log);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            ViewData["result"] = "Updated..!!";
            return View("Result");
        }
```

Comment: Is you controller `ShowMessageController`?

Comment: Confirm your controller name and also ensure you are using the correct overload of `BeginForm()`

Comment: Hi Friends,I checked all the possible things like controller name verfication, changing view name as well model name and also tried creating new view. But still Submit button does not work or doesn't transfer control to [Httppost] method

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing proper values for action and controller. As per your code "EventAssign" is your action and "ShowMessage" is your controller. Instead of passing values like this

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EventAssign", "ShowMessage", new { extMsgId = Model.ExternalMessageId, userId = Session["commitId"], currentController = Model.COMMIT_ID }, FormMethod.Post, new { id  = "formPosted1" }))
    {
      ...........
      ............
    }
```

you can pass values using hidden fields like this

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EventAssign", "ShowMessage", FormMethod.Post, new { id  = "formPosted1" }))
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="extMsgId" id="extMsgId" value="@Model.ExternalMessageId"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="@Session["commitId"]"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="currentController" id="currentController" value="@Model.COMMIT_ID"></input>
      ...........
      ............
    }
```